# Android gridview with images from URL

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm trying to build a gridview with thumb images loaded from the web.
What I have is an array of urls, which then I pass to an adapter customgrid (code will follow).
The download of the bitmap is done via async task.
The end result is that in 15 images, only 2 actually display, with the other 13 not displaying (but they all exist, and I've tried with the same url for all of them and this still happens. - check image in attach. 
[image: How it looks currently]

There's no error being thrown whatsoever.
Any help would be appreciated.

**CustomGrid.Java class:**

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final String[] ImageUrl;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;



public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,String[] ImageUrl ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
    this.web = web;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
        imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

        try
        {
            new LoadImage().execute(ImageUrl[position]);

        }catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}

private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {


        if(image != null){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }else{

        }
    }
}

}
```

**Main Activity code that loads the images : (web is just an array of strings and ImageUrl is an array with the url for the images)**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_trips_and_activities, frameLayout);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(TripsAndActivities.this, web, imageUrl);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(TripsAndActivities.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: At a quick glance, I would say your `GetView` is wrong in the else part.  You aren't setting anything if the View isn't null (where you should be setting an image, or something).  Not saying it will solve all your problems, but perhaps one.

Comment: Also, where are you setting the `imageView`'s image?

Comment: Thank you, but that won't be an issue. That bit code is actually never hit, and the bit with

new LoadImage().execute(ImageUrl[position]);

is called 15 times (which is the amount of images I'm trying to load).

Comment: ImageView is being set in the LoadImage call (Async Task in the bottom of the Adapter)

Comment: It will be hit, if you start scrolling...

Comment: So, problem is your `imageView` variable is being changed every time.  It changes before your images has loaded.

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#async-task, it does what you need to do.

Comment: But this imageview variable is being inflated , so in fact it should always be a different one which gets added to the gridview, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing, is that your `imageView` variable is changing (during your loop) and getting the images async.

By the time you get the image, your `imageView` is pointing to a different element.

Try the following

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
       try {
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will then need to use it like so

```
  BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
  task.execute(ImageUrl[position]);
```

or as you currently write it

```
new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(ImageUrl[position]);
```

Also, refactor your `GetView` to something like this

```
var view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
} 

var myImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

try {
    //You can further optimize the code, by storing the bitmap is some
    //cache, so when the user scrolls away, it doesn't throw the image 
    //away but keeps it for reuse once they scroll back.
    new LoadImage(myImageView).execute(ImageUrl[position]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return view;
```

Comment: Thank you,this has fixed the issue :)

Comment: Bare in mind the other issue I mentioned (when you have more images than the screen can hold and you need to scroll).

Comment: I currently have more than the screen holds, but seems to work fine.

Comment: Actualy @Johan, you might be right on that being weird.
I changed it to 

else {

            grid = (View) convertView;
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            try
            {
                new LoadImage(imageView).execute(ImageUrl[position]);

            }catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

But when I scroll down and up and down again, it gets the wrong images. But the code makes sense now I think.

Comment: Thank you. it keeps the same behaviour, ie: the 3 bottom images sometimes display the same image, others just repeats 2 and gets 1 correctly, and very randomly displays the 3 correct ones.

Comment: Ah, forgot to change the imageView to a local variable and not a global one, see update.

Comment: Makes sense, but still same behavior.